# Turning zero into negative

Tags: calculus

I have any amount of whole numbers in range from -6 to 6 (x)
in no specific sequence.
For example -2,1,0,5 .
If i go through each of them
negative values and zero should become (x-1) but positive numbers should stay intact.
So result is -3,1,-1,5
What formula i can use for this, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

$$f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z},\ f(n) = n + \frac{\mathrm{sgn}\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right) - 1}{2}$$

where $\mathrm{sgn}$ is the "sign function" or "signum function" which returns -1 for negative $n$, $0$ for $n = 0$ and $1$ for positive $n$.

Comment: nice, i can totally use it . Thanks for help